# Changing the Moodle E-mail template not work

Tags: php, moodle

I wanted to change the text in Moodle email message sent to the user when admin create the user. I changed the text in moodle\lang\en/moodle.php file and it was not success. I cleared browser cache and theme cache in Moodle also. But could not be success. Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried for purge all cache?

Comment: Yes Suman. Browser cache and theme cache was cleared. But nothing happened.

Comment: I purged the Moodle cache and it worked. Did not know what purging Moodle cache earlier. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The language strings are kept in a cache on the server. You will need to purge the cache to see the new string

Go to

```
/admin/purgecaches.php
```

Although it would be much better to change the string via language customisation rather than the code. Then when you upgrade Moodle, any language changes you make will still be there

```
/admin/tool/customlang/index.php
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention - during testing, you can switch off the language cache in config.php

```
$CFG->langstringcache = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. After purging the cache it worked well.